# Finding the probability of something happening

Tags: probability

would the answer to this question be right by any chance? Thanks.

A stain remover is tried out on various stain patches. It is found that 40% of stain is removed on the first application, but the remaining stains become resistant so that the proportion removed in any subsequent application is only one half that of the preceding application. Find the probability that a stain patch will survive 3 applications:

Answer: 40/( 100)  ×  20/( 100)  ×  10/( 100) =  8000/1000000 = 0.008

Comment: Prob of stain surviving application 1, 2 and 3 = 0.6, 0.8 and 0.9 respectively. So, answer should be (0.6)(0.8)(0.9)

Comment: Multiply all 3 together? answer: 0.432?

Comment: Yes, but's it's a strange question, since the stain can never be 100% removed...

Comment: It certainly is, but I guess some stains can never be removed ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your input by the way.